# What is wrong with the following JSON?

Tags: json

```
{
    "id": 1001,
    "text": "Core Java - Collections",
    "description": "public static void main(String args[ ]) { \n&nbsp;int x =10;\n}",
    "passingScore": 10,
    "totalQuestions": 20,
    "technologyId": 10,
    "subTechnologyId": 101
}{ // fails on this line
    "id": 1000,
    "text": "Core Java",
    "description": "public static void main(String args[ ]) { \n&nbsp;int x =10;\n}",
    "passingScore": 10,
    "totalQuestions": 5,
    "technologyId": 10,
    "subTechnologyId": 100
}
```

I do not see any fault with the above JSON, but somehow this fails. Could anyone please help me spot the error?

Comment: What makes you think "it fails"? (Gosh -- 1 minute on the 'net: you are missing a comma.)

Comment: No comma between the two "objects", and no surrounding "array".  Go to json.org to learn the JSON syntax -- it only takes 5-10 minutes.

Comment: You can try to validate it here: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Yes, you need a comma after } and before { which then makes it an array.

Comment: @Scott - It's not an array until you put `[]` around it.

Comment: Note that some web services provide data in the above format.  To handle them you need a parser that will stop when it's read a complete item from the input stream, and then tell you where it left off so you can tell it where to resume to read the next.  Not very nice, but that's the way it goes sometimes.

Comment: @HotLicks: There are some protocols that are _defined_ as a stream of JSON objects. Most notably, JSON-RPC (although it's most often used over HTTP, where each JSON object is in a separate request, so you don't notice…).

Comment: Yes thank you I thought that was obvious.The missing comma seemed less obvious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary issue is that you can only have **one** top-level item, which must be either an object (`{}`) or an array (`[]`). The second issue is that if you have multiple items, you must separate them with a comma.

For instance, this is valid:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1001,
        "text": "Core Java - Collections",
        "description": "public static void main(String args[ ]) { \n&nbsp;int x =10;\n}",
        "passingScore": 10,
        "totalQuestions": 20,
        "technologyId": 10,
        "subTechnologyId": 101
    },
    {
        "id": 1000,
        "text": "Core Java",
        "description": "public static void main(String args[ ]) { \n&nbsp;int x =10;\n}",
        "passingScore": 10,
        "totalQuestions": 5,
        "technologyId": 10,
        "subTechnologyId": 100
    }
]
```

There I've added `[]` to make it an array, and a comma between the objects.

Alternately, if it shouldn't be an array, you could make it an object with two keys:

```
{
    "first": {
        "id": 1001,
        "text": "Core Java - Collections",
        "description": "public static void main(String args[ ]) { \n&nbsp;int x =10;\n}",
        "passingScore": 10,
        "totalQuestions": 20,
        "technologyId": 10,
        "subTechnologyId": 101
    },
    "second": {
        "id": 1000,
        "text": "Core Java",
        "description": "public static void main(String args[ ]) { \n&nbsp;int x =10;\n}",
        "passingScore": 10,
        "totalQuestions": 5,
        "technologyId": 10,
        "subTechnologyId": 100
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not JSON. A JSON document is either an array or a dictionary. You have two dictionaries. Like { } { }. You would need an array of dictionaries, separated by a comma. Like [ { }, { } ].

To fix this: Tell whoever supplied the supposed "JSON" to fix it. Alternative you can parse whatever this is manually. Actually, all you need is find the matching closing braces, split the data into pieces and parse them individually. Very ugly; I'd refuse to do it.